# How to group column headers in Primeng table

Tags: header, primeng

I am using PrimeNG to display a table data in my angular app. There is a scenario where we have to group the columns under one header like below. Is there a way to group the columns.
Ex:

S.no               Employee Info             Address
Lname | FName | DOB        St. Num | St. Address | City | Zip

Answer (score 1):

There is one way.

You have to use the rowspan and colspan properties of th or td. RowSpan is the number rows the cell will occupy. Colspan indicates the number of columns the cell will occupy. This is the official example:

```
<p-table [value]="sales">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="3">Product</th>
            <th colspan="4">Sale Rate</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Sales</th>
            <th colspan="2">Profits</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Last Year</th>
            <th>This Year</th>
            <th>Last Year</th>
            <th>This Year</th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-sale>
        <tr>
            <td>{{sale.product}}</td>
            <td>{{sale.lastYearSale}}%</td>
            <td>{{sale.thisYearSale}}%</td>
            <td>{{sale.lastYearProfit | currency: 'USD'}}</td>
            <td>{{sale.thisYearProfit | currency: 'USD'}}</td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

I put the [link](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table/colgroup) where it's explained.

I don't know if this is what you are looking for.